# How to select HTML <title> tag using only CSS?

Tags: html, css, sass

I was wondering if it is possible to have a CSS property that is only applied if an HTML  tag is present and with the expected value, I have a component that is rendered several times however in 1 particular case I need it to have a different margin value.

I understand I can write a JS script that does this however I was wondering if it is possible to do this using only CSS.

I tried using the :not and :where CSS selectors for this specific case however was unable to properly select this HTML  as shown below:

```
&:not(title[value="Phone"]) {
  .css-class & {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to include the HTML

Comment: The selector doesn't make much sense, the title element can't have a `value` attribute.